# Aix switch user

Tags: unix, aix

logged in as user xxxx

```
pwd
...../user/xxxx
```

tried to switch user using su command

```
su yyyy
pwd
...../user/xxxx
```

pwd --> still pointing to xxxx user itself

How to switch user in Aix and have the pwd display the new user directory i.e .../user/yyyy??

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites http://superuser.com OR http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Below did the trick

su - yyyy

Got this from 
https://www.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds5/su.htm